# Same named items in one javascript object, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I try to do something like this:

```
var obj = {id: id, items: "asdf", items: "sdff", test: varTest};
```

**BUT** I need to add the two same named items called 'items' dynamically. Because it won't be always the same number of these elements. How can I add them to this object, without overwriting them itselfs?

Thank you very much.

PS: I know that this is probably not a good idea, but I use an API so I can't change this. I need to give them the same name.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use same key multiple times in an object. You can use array.

```
var obj = {id: id, items:["asdf", "sdff"], test: varTest};
```

This will be easy to access the elements having same semantics.

To add items use,

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(items)) {
    obj.items.push(newVal);
} else {
    obj.items = [newVal];
}
```

Comment: The Problem is, that I need to send this object to the API. And they require that I have multiple items called "items". I know its ridiculous.

Comment: You should tell them that their API is broken

Comment: If you are sending as JSON can't you just construct the string with multiple `items` and let them deal with it at their end - rather than creating an object?

Comment: @SexyTurnip: How would I do this?

Comment: `I need to send this object to the API. And they require that I have multiple items called "items".` In that case you would most likely need to send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Indeed you are right. But I use a Class from them, which I send an JSON, which itself transforms this to the urlencoded-String.

Comment: Can you link to any API documentation?